# Possible to have a button always enabled inside a groupbox?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I was wondering if it is possible to have a button inside a groupbox that is always enabled. even if the groupbox is not?

EDIT:
Here are 2 images that might explain more what i'm trying to do:

Enabled view: 
http://www.imagecabin.com/index.php?view=322581721739323a1fdd1bb0d&html=1

disabled view: 
http://www.imagecabin.com/index.php?view=32258209592bb28651742381c&html=1

As seen in the images, the red circled buttons are the ones that I always want to be clickable. 
The state of the start/stop/pause buttons in the groupboxs is handled by events. This is why I disable the groupboxes if the server is stopped.

Comment: What functionality do the circled buttons provide?

Comment: They popup a more detailed overview of the current actions (whits are also seen in the textbox, but the textbox is more for real time viewing) for the specified manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @JonH on this.  Conventions are critical from a user experience perspective.  Only break them when you have a **good** reason to.

If you are absolutely set on doing it though you can avoid the enabling/disabling problems described above by moving the button outside of the group box and then using absolute positioning to place the button on top of the group box.  It would have the same parent control as the group box, but it would appear to be inside the group box for users.

UPDATE:  After seeing the screenshots and understanding what the buttons do, I would either:

1. Move the buttons out of the group boxes and put them on a
   toolbar/menu or another part of the screen.  Or...
2. Build a custom control which behaves like a group box (i.e. header and content
   area) that has a button which raises a popout event or something
   like that.  Either way, I would make sure the button appears to be
   part of the control's header so the intent is more intuitive.

Comment: I'm trying to move position them absolutely but the button is going behind the groupbox. how do you solve that?

Comment: Solved it: Cut & past the control

Answer (score 2):

Instead of disabling your groupBox, why not just disable all controls in it except for your button?

```
foreach (Control C in yourGroupBox.Controls.OfType<Control>())
   if (C != yourButton)
      C.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Thinking outside the box, I like it :)

Comment: The problem is my other controls are controlled by events if they should or shouldn't been disabled. this overrides my buttons enabled status if I try it your way. That's why I disable the whole groupbox.

Comment: @Oxillery - Well I'm not sure I follow your last comment.  The short answer to this question is no.  There's a decent workaround with my answer, and JonH is also giving you some advice below.  Once you've resolved this question, I would ask a new, more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

If the state of a control (enabled vs disabled / visible vs hidden) is independent from the parent container then it should not be placed inside of a parent control.

If it is inside the groupbox and the groupbox is disabled then the button will also be disabled.  The proper way to do this is to have the button outside the groupbox as its state is independent of the groupbox's state.